# RabbitMq: prohibit consumer from creating queues

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

Our java spring boot application is creating/declaring queues (if they do not exist) after successful connection to a certain exchange / topic.

Is it possible (from rabbitmq admin panel) to prohibit certain users (in this case the one used by this spring boot app) from creating/declaring a queue if it does no exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the permissions of the user a Spring-Boot app uses to connect to the broker.

This is achieved by supplying 3 regex (configuration, write, read), if you let the first one empty (`"^$"`), the user will not be able to delare any queue as mentionned in the [complete documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#permissions)

You can also disable the RabbitAdmin bean by adding the following property to the app configuration file `spring.rabbitmq.dynamic=false`, so Spring will not try to declare anything.